# Bootstrap: modal.js v3.2.0 Nested modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup, bootstrap-modal

I am new on Bootstrap.

- My Requirement is to open Modal Popup in a page. (Done).
- Open Modal Popup required to open another Modal Popup. (Done).

**Facing Issue :**

When I goes to close the nested (Second) Modal Popup, both popup is closed at a time. Because I Use "data-dismiss='modal'" to close the modals. is there any other way to close Nested Modal Popup.

Comment: Did the modals have different `id's`? Can you please add your nested modals code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah now I understand!
You'll need to close your modal using javascript then :) I've written a little function here. Just add the "closeModal" class to the button which you want to close the modal for.

Basically it finds the parent modal that the button belongs to and closes that modal. Hopefully this helps and you can change it around if needs be.

```
    $(".closeModal").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide")
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjazcz5e/4/

Bootstrap provides a .modal() JQuery plugin to let you control modals. Take a look:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I am asking a nesting Modal. First Modal Popup contain a link to open another Modal Popup. http://jsfiddle.net/JigneshPatel/kjazcz5e/2/

Comment: Ah I got you! Sorry I misunderstood what you wanted. I've updated my answer :)

Comment: I know this is old, but for the next person to find this, you can do this without any javascript. use data-toggle instead of data-dismiss, and set the data-target to the modal that you want to close. I updated the jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/kjazcz5e/24/